# onDraw() method mandatory in custom view?

Tags: android, layout, view

I see a custom view class only have the constructors like `MyView(Context context), MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attars) and MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`. There's no onDraw() method in it. So, is the onDraw() method mandatory in custom view? Otherwise, how the custom view takes effect without the onDraw() method?

Comment: It's not going to be much use without one ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a custom view you need to extend an existing one (The most basic view in android is android.view.View). You don't have to implement onDraw() method if you don't want to because the parent view has a basic implementation. You would normally extend that method if you want your custom view to do some specific drawing.

I would suggest you to read bit more about Object Oriented programming and Polymorphism here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html